# Multiple Language Support in Android App with Google Cloud Translation

Tags: android, kotlin

How to implement multiple language support in android using Google Cloud Translation
how can we translate api response and set that value in labels

i try to translate words its done but how can we translate api response in android which is in  json form

Comment: There are 2 approaches. One is to make your API support multi language by accepting a language code from the request and output the corresponding language. The other one, which I prefer more, is to make your program understand the API response, then instead of printing the text from the API response, you pick the string from the localized strings.xml resources according to your understanding of the responded data.

Comment: we our app case its not possible to store all data in localized String format 
There will user define data help me with api response which is in json format to convert that data in multiple language using any api